# Prevent height of grid item from expanding all available height

Tags: javascript, html, css, foreach

My code is generally working fine but there is one small issue. Everytime that I want to toggle a particular players' box the box expands (as it should) but then the other players' boxes that are in the same row as the box im toggling will expand too. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

```js
const arsenal = {
    name: 'Arsenal',
    city: 'London',
    startingLineup: {
        gk: {name:'Aaron Ramsdale', age: 24, country:'England', img:'img/ramsdale.png'},
        lb: {name:'Oleksandr Zinchenko', age: 26, country:'Ukraine', img: 'img/zinchenko.jpg'},
        rb: {name:'Ben White', age: 25, country:'England', img: 'img/white.png'},
        lcb: {name:'Gabriel Magalhaes', age: 25, country:'Brazil',img: 'img/gabriel.png'},
        rcb: {name: 'William Saliba', age: 22, country:'France', img: 'img/saliba.png'},
        cdm: {name:'Thomas Partey',age: 29,country:'Ghana', img: 'img/partey.png'},
        cm: {name:'Granit Xhaka',age:30,country:'Switzerland',img: 'img/xhaka face.png'},
        cam: {name:'Martin Odegaard',age:23,country:'Norway',img: 'img/odegaard.png'},
        lw: {name:'Gabriel Martinelli',age:21, country:'Brazil',img: 'img/martinelli.png'},
        rw: {name:'Bukayo Saka',age:21,country:'England',img:'img/saka.png'},
        st: {name:'Gabriel Jesus',age:26,country:'Brazil', img: 'img/jesus.png'}
    }
}

let container = document.querySelector(".container")

Object.entries(arsenal.startingLineup).forEach(([key,value]) => {
    let player = document.createElement("div")
    let playerData = document.createElement("div")

    let image = document.createElement("img")
    let name = document.createElement("h3")
    let age = document.createElement("h3")
    let country = document.createElement("h3")

    image.src = value.img
    let nameNode = document.createTextNode(value.name)
    let ageNode = document.createTextNode(value.age)
    let countryNode = document.createTextNode(value.country)

    name.appendChild(nameNode)
    age.appendChild(ageNode)
    country.appendChild(countryNode)

    image.classList.add("image")
    name.classList.add("h3")
    age.classList.add("h3")
    country.classList.add("h3")

    playerData.append(name, age, country)
    player.append(image, playerData)

    playerData.classList.add("playerData")
    player.classList.add("player")

    container.appendChild(player)

    player.addEventListener("click",() => {
        player.classList.toggle("active")
    })
})

let title = document.querySelector("h1")
title.innerHTML = arsenal.name
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(203, 17, 17);
  font-family: arial;
}

.container {
  background-color: aquamarine transparent;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.player {
  background-color: rgb(168, 21, 21);
  width: fit-content;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.player img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px
}

.playerData {
  display: none;
  max-height: 0;
}

.player.active .playerData {
  background-color: rgb(118, 11, 11);
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  max-height: 200px;
  display: block;
}

h3 {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<div class="container">
  <!--<div class="player">
        <img class="image" src="img/jesus.png">
        <div class="playerData">
            <h3 class="name">Gabriel Jesus</h3>
            <h3 class="age">25</h3>
            <h3 class="country">Brazil</h3>
        </div>
    </div>-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that with grid, the child elements expand to all the available height. To prevent your cards from expanding all the height, you can wrap them in another div like this :

```js
const arsenal = {
    name: 'Arsenal',
    city: 'London',
    startingLineup: {
        gk: {name:'Aaron Ramsdale', age: 24, country:'England', img:'img/ramsdale.png'},
        lb: {name:'Oleksandr Zinchenko', age: 26, country:'Ukraine', img: 'img/zinchenko.jpg'},
        rb: {name:'Ben White', age: 25, country:'England', img: 'img/white.png'},
        lcb: {name:'Gabriel Magalhaes', age: 25, country:'Brazil',img: 'img/gabriel.png'},
        rcb: {name: 'William Saliba', age: 22, country:'France', img: 'img/saliba.png'},
        cdm: {name:'Thomas Partey',age: 29,country:'Ghana', img: 'img/partey.png'},
        cm: {name:'Granit Xhaka',age:30,country:'Switzerland',img: 'img/xhaka face.png'},
        cam: {name:'Martin Odegaard',age:23,country:'Norway',img: 'img/odegaard.png'},
        lw: {name:'Gabriel Martinelli',age:21, country:'Brazil',img: 'img/martinelli.png'},
        rw: {name:'Bukayo Saka',age:21,country:'England',img:'img/saka.png'},
        st: {name:'Gabriel Jesus',age:26,country:'Brazil', img: 'img/jesus.png'}
    }
}

let container = document.querySelector(".container")

Object.entries(arsenal.startingLineup).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  let wrapper = document.createElement("div")
  let player = document.createElement("div")
  let playerData = document.createElement("div")

  let image = document.createElement("img")
  let name = document.createElement("h3")
  let age = document.createElement("h3")
  let country = document.createElement("h3")

  image.src = value.img
  let nameNode = document.createTextNode(value.name)
  let ageNode = document.createTextNode(value.age)
  let countryNode = document.createTextNode(value.country)

  name.appendChild(nameNode)
  age.appendChild(ageNode)
  country.appendChild(countryNode)

  image.classList.add("image")
  name.classList.add("h3")
  age.classList.add("h3")
  country.classList.add("h3")

  playerData.append(name, age, country)
  player.append(image, playerData)
  wrapper.append(player)

  playerData.classList.add("playerData")
  player.classList.add("player")
  wrapper.classList.add("wrapper")

  container.appendChild(wrapper)

  player.addEventListener("click", () => {
    player.classList.toggle("active")
  })
})

let title = document.querySelector("h1")
title.innerHTML = arsenal.name
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(203, 17, 17);
  font-family: arial;
}

.container {
  background-color: aquamarine transparent;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.player {
  background-color: rgb(168, 21, 21);
  width: fit-content;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.player img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px
}

.playerData {
  display: none;
  max-height: 0;
}

.player.active .playerData {
  background-color: rgb(118, 11, 11);
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  max-height: 200px;
  display: block;
}

h3 {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<div class="container">
  <!--<div class="player">
    <img class="image" src="img/jesus.png">
    <div class="playerData">
      <h3 class="name">Gabriel Jesus</h3>
      <h3 class="age">25</h3>
      <h3 class="country">Brazil</h3>
    </div>
  </div>-->
</div>
```